Setting up routes for dashboard and child component
I have a simple React dashboard that fetches brand data and displays brand options to the user. The dashboard has two main components Dashboard and Results. Results is Dashboard's child component that displays selected brands page names. It relies on several props to function. I'd like to implement deep linking by leveraging react-router-dom, but I'm having some trouble. Every time I copy/paste URL into another window, I'm routed to Dashboard and not Results. The URL structure is like so, localhost:5173/{brand}/{pageName}.
Are my routes set up correctly? I have the routes nested, because dashboard has to pull in data for results. Maybe, I'm approaching this completely wrong, but my only goal is to set up deep linking, so that I can share a URL from my app with other users.
For example, if I navigate to http://localhost:5173/, I'll see a list of brands (brandA, brandB, brandC, etc.). Once I choose a brand I'll navigate to http://localhost:5173/brand. and then I'll see a list of pages to choose from. Once I choose a page, I navigate to http://localhost:5173/brand/page. At this point everything is fine and renders like it's supposed to. However, if I copy and paste the URL http://localhost:5173/brand/page>into a new window I'm routed to the default dashboard and not the brand specific results.
function App() {
  const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = useState<SiteData | null>(null)

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={selectedBrand}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route path="/:brand/*" element={<Results />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

export default App



export default function Dashboard() {
    const [siteData, setSiteData] = useState<SiteData[]>([])
    const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = useState<SiteData | null>(null)
    const [showNewWindow, setShowNewWindow] = useState(false)
    const [latestDate, setLatestDate] = useState<string>('')
    const [latestUrl, setLatestUrl] = useState<string>('')
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')


    const fetchImageFiles()

    // remianing logic.......

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={selectedBrand}>
            {
                !showNewWindow && !selectedBrand ?
                    // DashboardUI
                                                :
                    <Results>
                        onClose={handleCloseWindow}
                        siteData={selectedBrand}
                        latestUrl={latestDiffUrl}
                        latestDate={selectedBrand.date} // Use the latest run date
                    </Results>
            }
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}




Are you using  inside ?

If you navigate to any "/:brand/*" route path then both Dashboard and Results should render. Are you saying that Results is never rendered when on a sub-route, you just see Dashboard and no results content? Can you [edit] to include both these route components for a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, and clarify what you are expecting to see rendered? Are there any errors in the console?

@KostasMinaidis, no I'm not using .

@DerrickMullins I think that's the reason why you don't see the child rendered.

@DrewReese Correct, Results never renders and I'm routed to default dashboard and not brand specific results.

Are you expecting to see both Dashboard and Results, or just one or the other, e.g. just Dashboard on "/" and just Results on "/:brand/*"?

See: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

Also, how are you hosting/serving this app? The behavior you describe where you are able to correctly navigate to the nested routes and everything is fine, but if you attempt to navigate to them directly it doesn't work leads me to believe the server isn't serving the app/page correctly.

"no I'm not using " - If this is the case then the code you have posted would never render the Results component via a nested route since there's nowhere to output the rendered result, e.g. no Outlet rendered by the dashboard layout route. Is the code you shared in the post accurate?

@DrewReese, our production dashboard will be hosted on GitHub Pages, but I've been testing this on my local. I'm not sure if thats an issue?
Also, if I copy/paste http://localhost:5173/brand/page into another browser, I'd expect to only see Results component and not Dashboard

Ok, seeing some progress after adding . Now if I copy/paste localhost:5173/{brand}/{pageName} I get a console error about data being undefined, but at least I'm not being routed to Dashboard anymore.

"I'd expect to only see Results component and not Dashboard" - But you are rendering Dashboard as a layout route component, so it will always be rendered on "/" and any "/" sub-route. If you don't want this behavior then un-nest the Results sub-routes. Does this answer help answer/address your question/issue?

@DrewReese, adding Outlet makes sense, thank you. Now, my question is, how should I be passing props from parent component Dashboard to child component Results?

Is your Dashboard component directly rendering the Results component so it can actually pass props to it? You've yet to update your post to include a complete [mcve] so it's unclear what interaction and/or data these routed component need/use.

Sorry, this is for work, so I'm trying to be discreet. Yes, Dashboard is directly rendering the Results component. Updated original post.

If Dashboard is directly rendering Results then there is no need for the Outlet and nested route, just fetch the data in Dashboard and pass it down as props to Results. In fact, you don't even need the router, this is just vanilla React & JSX at this point.

As it's not quite clear from the original question, what the expected output should look like, here are two options that will work for you in either case:
Case 1: If you want to see the <Dashboard /> Component rendered at the / path and the <Results /> Component rendered at the /:brand/* path without the <Dashboard /> included in the output, use the following routes setup:
<Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
<Route path="/:brand/*" element={<Results />} />

Case 2:
If you want to see the <Dashboard /> Component rendered at the / path and the <Results /> Component rendered at the /:brand/* path as part of the <Dashboard /> Component, use the following routes setup:
<Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
  <Route path="/:brand/*" element={<Results />} />
</Route>

While ensuring that the <Dashboard /> Component has an <Outlet /> Component to render the nested route element:
function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      Dashboard
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}


Here is a very basic setup for sharing state between the <Dashboard /> and <Results /> components in the 2nd scenario (Results is nested) using Context:
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext();

function Dashboard() {
  const ctx = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <div>
      Dashboard
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          ctx.setSelectedBrand(Math.random());
        }}
      >
        Fetch data
      </button>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

function Results() {
  // Results will receive the data updated by <Dashboard />
  const ctx = useContext(Context);
  return <div>Results {ctx.selectedBrand} </div>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = useState(null);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ setSelectedBrand, selectedBrand }}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route path="/:brand/*" element={<Results />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

Yet, another option is through the useOutletContext hook:
import { useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

function Dashboard() {
  const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      Dashboard
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setSelectedBrand(Math.random());
        }}
      >
        Fetch data
      </button>
      <Outlet context={selectedBrand} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Results() {
  // Results will receive the data updated by <Dashboard />
  const selectedBrand = useOutletContext();
  return <div>Results {selectedBrand}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
          <Route path="/:brand/*" element={<Results />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

References: Outlet

When I don't nest the routes, I get an error, because Dashboard is responsible for fetching the data needed to render results Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageNames'). I tried passing context to Result via Context.Provider, but I guess it's not working as expected? Do I need to explicitly pass the props to Results in my route?

I believe you should update your code to provide some more context for that. It's really hard to give some directions unless you can provide code related to the Dashboard and the Context.

@DerrickMullins I've updated my answer with a barebones example of how to pass state from Dashboard to Results in the case where you want to use the nested route setup.
